# Best approach for web component using BEM and SASS

Tags: css, sass, bem

I want to know about the best approach when we have to write a reusable web component (considering possible override by users) using BEM and SASS:

Let suppose to have a main element and a child element, so using bem:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__child"></div>
</div>
```

I want to focus on two approaches in SASS:

**Approach 1)**

```
.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;

  .main__child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
 }
}
```

this correspond to

```
.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.main .main__child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

**Approach 2)**

```
.main{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;

  &__child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

this correspond to

```
.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.main__child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

In the first approach we have a more specific rule so that we can select only classes .main__child that are descendants of .main class. (strong relationship)

In the second approach the two classes are technically separated in the css. Due to the ampersand (&).

I'm confusing on it. Reading on the web it seems that the common pattern is the second approach.
Can you give me more explanations? Even considering class overriding?

Comment: If we're following the BEM methodology then the selector .main__child already suggests that it's a descendant of .main and that it should only be used in that situation, so Approach 1) is redundant. And it also increases the selector's specificity which is something I try to avoid.

Comment: ok it sounds good thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common pattern is - just like you said - the second approach. This approach however has one big downside to it: being able to search on the component name.

Let's say you are building an overview of all the colors of vehicles, you will get

```
.car {
  // Styling of a car

  &--red {
    color: red;
  }
}

.bike {
  // Styling of a bike

  &--red {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

The point is this is that `blocks` always are unique, but `elements` and `modifiers` are not. If you now need to search the styling of the red bike, you can't search `.bike--red`, because this is nowhere in your code (except for the rendered css) and if you search `--red` you will get all the red vehicles.

To fix this, it's easier to set up your styling like this:

```
.car {
  // Styling of a car
}

.car--red {
  color: red;
}

.bike {
  // Styling of a bike
}

.bike--red {
  color: red;
}
```

Your styling still gets overwritten the right way, everything has a specificity of 1 (see [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) for more information about specificity) and you can search for the entire elements name in your code!

Comment: i have understand your answer but in this way we cannot take advantage of SASS indentation...or i'm wrong?

Comment: We're not taking advantage of it, you're right. It's a tradeoff. But I too, as Daniel suggests, prefer to be able to perform searches in that way than to take advantage of SASS's nesting feature in this situation.